# Powershell comparing 2 csv files

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to compare 2 files that both contain email addresses. For example text1.csv has 800 addresses and text2.csv has 200. Most of the email addresses in text2.csv are in text1.csv but not all of them. I need to export all the email addresses from text2.csv that are NOT in text1.csv. The property on both files is email

I tried something like this but I dont get the correct outcome:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\test1.csv) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\test2.csv) | Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }
```

I also tried this without result

```
$file2 | Where-Object { $_.email -NotIn $file1 }
```

Comment: Yes, both cv file headers' name are email

Comment: I am pretty new to powershell when I use ``-Property email`` i get a empty return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- By using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), you end up comparing *whole lines* from your input files.
- In order to compare *column values* from CSV files, you must first convert your input files to *objects*, using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), whose *properties* (reflecting the column values) you can then compare; in your case, the `.email` property:

```sh
Compare-Object -PassThru (Import-Csv C:\scripts\test1.csv).email `
                         (Import-Csv C:\scripts\test2.csv).email | 
  Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }
```

Note:

- [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)'s `-PassThru` switch directly passes the differing objects through, decorated with a `.SideIndicator` ETS property, instead of wrapping them in a `[pscustomobject]` wrapper whose `.InputObject` contains the respective original object.
- Even though, with multiple data rows in the CSV, `Import-Csv` returns an *array* of objects, you can access `.email` directly on that array in order to get the property values of all *elements* in the array, which is a convenient feature known as [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).
- For brevity, I'm using *positional* arguments above (e.g., `C:\scripts\test1.csv` instead of `-Path C:\scripts\test1.csv`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
$emails = (Import-Csv -Path 'X:\file1.csv').email
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\file2.csv' |
          Where-Object { $emails -notcontains $_.email }

# output to new file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\missingEmails.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```